# "Cheat sheet" for homotopy type theory/Martin Lof intuitionistic type theory

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Is there a table somewhere of the commonly used types along with the formation rules, constructors, eliminators, computation rules, recursors and  inductions ?

Whenever I'm going an exercise I have to keep flicking back and forth to find the appropriate definition.

Comment: Have you looked at Section A.2 of the homotopy type theory book? For instance the rules for dependent functions and dependent pairs are listed in Sections A.2.4 and A.2.5.

Comment: It's almost what I want. I think the best solution is for me to write my own.

Comment: If you do so, then consider linking to it here, so others can benefit from your work as well. :-) Note that the TeX source of the homotopy type theory book is available online, so you might be able to save some typesetting work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on sources of the HoTT Book, I made some cheatsheets per some parts of this book. The missing parts will be added later or you might want to contribute it.

https://github.com/jonaprieto/hott-cheatsheet

Comment: This looks very useful, but I'm getting "not found" when I click on the pdf links.

Comment: It is perhaps because I archived the repo. You can still clone it and generate the pdfs. Otherwise, send me an email and I can send you back the pdfs.